# Get part of the content from the website to different one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to get the part of the different website page to my website content.
i have tried to do that with sending an ajax request to that webpage , but getting an cross domain access error 
have any idea how to do that?

for example, i want to get this part only http://gyazo.com/600ee9facec408dd56a69c907293ebed from this website http://www.simbagames.com/en/aboutus.aspx 
to my existing webpage, and put that content in my webpage content part

this is how i was tring to do that

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    type:'POST',
        url: link,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "html", // this is important
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
         }
    })
```

No need iframes

is that possible?

Comment: if these sites are yours, Yes you can. Otherwise no

Comment: You should check cUrl

Comment: and ho i have to do that? cUrl what is that, where can i use it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a header to response in aboutus.aspx. Or like Kasyx says, give up javascript and get with cUrl

**"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"**

Comment: You need to add a header to response in aboutus.aspx not a request in other page that you make an ajax. Is it not clear?

Comment: ok, i understand, but is that enough? what if i put it in the header.aspx wich i am importing for pages , and the sintax also,  if i add it like this < (BTW with quotes or no? ) Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *;   > will that work? no errors?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cant because in addition by setting **"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"**

A server supporting CORS must respond to requests with several access control headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

By default, CORS requests are not made with cookies. If the server includes this header, then we can send cookies along with our request by setting the withCredentials option to true.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials (optional)
```

If we set the withCredentials option in our request to true, but the server does not respond with this header, then the request will fail and vice versa.

**if server not responding you with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"` then you cant fetch data**

[more about that](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)